# Change installed AppleScript version

Tags: applescript

Is there any way to change the installed version of AppleScript?

After mistakenly identifying my version of AppleScript as 1.0 by using a [15 year old script](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/applescript-in-a/1565928415/ch01s05.html) (turns out that just checks the version of the script you are currently running, which is implicitly 1.0) and trying to figure out how to upgrade, I was wondering how/if it's possible to change the installed version of AppleScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change the version of AppleScript installed with OS X. AppleScript is a core part of the operating system.

If you are running the latest version of OS X, then you have the latest AppleScript.

Answer (score 0):

The linked script to get the AppleScript version is bogus. To get your current AppleScript version open AppleScript-Editor/Script -Editor.

In the menubar got to Script-Editor->About Script-Editor

The current AppleScript version is just below the AppleScript-Editor/Script -Editor version number.

Examples:

- Mavericks 10.9.5:       AppleScript 2.3.2
- El Capitan 10.11.3:     AppleScript 2.5