# AppleScript version

Tags: applescript, macos

I've tried to figure out my AppleScript version, and arrived at a contradiction.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript), the latest AppleScript version is 2.7. According to [this Ask Different answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/225217), if I run the latest version of OS X, then I have the latest AppleScript version. I run macOS Sierra version 10.12.4. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS#Release_history), the latest version of OS X is macOS 10.12 Sierra. Therefore I run the latest version of macOS. Therefore I run the latest AppleScript version. Therefore my AppleScript version is 2.7.

However, according to [this Ask Different answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/225221), my current AppleScript version is specified in the 'About Script Editor' dialog of the Script Editor application, and the 'About Script Editor' dialog of my Script Editor application says

> AppleScript 2.5

We have arrived at a contradiction!

How can this be explained? How can I install the latest AppleScript version?

Comment: The reference in the wiki article citing 2.7 seems to be kind of strange (the linked page doesn't seem to mention any version number at all). Nevertheless, the accepted answer in the original question is still true: the most recent version of AplleScript is part of the most recent version of macOS

Comment: Wikipedia is not an authoritative source!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia is incorrect. The editor appears to have confused the version of Script Editor.app with the version of AppleScript.

- The latest version of AppleScript as of macOS Sierra 10.12.4 is AppleScript 2.5.
- Yosemite introduced Script Editor 2.7, which is what is mentioned in the Wikipedia article with a link to a blog post about Yosemite, and as of macOS 10.12.4 Script Editor is now at version 2.9.

You can find a full list of AppleScript versions with their OS release which I compiled for Stack Overflow Documentation:

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/applescript/5271/getting-started-with-applescript#a=versions

Comment: Hi,The documentation feature is now removed, can i get this information elsewhere? Thanks!